# MacOS Kitematic How To Configure Volumes

Tags: macos, docker, volumes, kitematic

I'm the docker newest user. I create container by Kitematic, but why my Configure Volumes is empty, and how to add some folder?

I can use command to add volume:

```
docker run -it -v /home/dock/Downloads:/usr/Downloads:ro ubuntu64 /bin/bash
```

But how to do this by Kitematic?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

**What U need exactly with Docker?**

Docker is so complicated. On macOS exist problem with performance, need to replace bundled sync with **docker-sync**.

Additionally to docs look at https://github.com/veggiemonk/awesome-docker

Comment: I just want to create PHP development environment. The mac environment is Differ for centos. then I want to edit html/php file on the mac, then share with the Docker,But the Volume can't work.

Comment: e,I know that, but the question is how to enable the volume. and why Configure Volumes is empty.

Comment: "docker run -it -v /home/dock/Downloads:/usr/Downloads ubuntu64 /bin/bash"
I can use the command to add volume, but how to add by Kitematic?

Comment: Kitematic just in beta and for lazy purposes. Use .yml config files to set options.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way at the moment
See this https://forums.docker.com/t/modifying-or-adding-volumes/1287/3